# Is trap agent has to be same related to trap management console

Tags: c#, .net, snmp, snmp-trap

I'm new to this network programming and I been looking for trap agent to send traps in C#. The currently in use trap agent is TrapGen.exe but I have to replace it with the in-house designed one. but I don't know where to start.

And also is that trap agent has to be same or related to trap management console(trap receiver on the server)?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding all resources what I found SNMP agent doesn't has to be same as management console.
You can make your own agent using C#.
the best library I have found is sharpsnmplib by Lex tm.